# Is there an accepted maximum line length for SMTP header fields?

Tags: smtp, mime4j

**Question**

What is a good value to use as "max header line length" if there's no standard?

Is there some kind of informal standard for what the maximum length of an SMTP header line should be?

---

**Context**

I use [Mime4J](https://james.apache.org/mime4j/) for parsing SMTP messages.

Recently, I had a parsing failure related to a very long header line, caused by a header apparently added by [Microsoft Forefront](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Forefront).
The offending header line looks like:

```
x-forefront-antispam-report: 
    CIP:94.245.94.31;IPV:NLI;CTRY:IE;EFV:NLI;SFV:NSPM;SFS:(10019020)(4636009)(136003)(376002)(396003)(346002)(39850400004)(2980300002)(62414003)(199004)(189003)(11346002)(2501003)(6916009)(5640700003)(8936002)(126002)(76176011)(9326002)(486006)(2476003)(476003)(33656002)(3480700005)(2906002)(99286004)(568964002)(21480400003)(446003)(606006)(6506007)(15974865002)(14454004)(61614004)(229853002)(33964004)(53546011)(71200400001)(71190400001)(26005)(102836004)(66066001)(186003)(5660300002)(5070765005)(6246003)(246002)(235185007)(55016002)(316002)(966005)(7696005)(356004)(3846002)(8676002)(9686003)(86362001)(54896002)(6306002)(790700001)(236005)(6116002)(106002)(7066003)(7636002)(7736002)(70586007)(25786009)(70206006)(7116003)(52536014)(14444005)(74316002)(7596002)(16586007)(336012)(53386004)(5024004)(45080400002)(478600001)(71440200001);DIR:OUT;SFP:1102;SCL:1;SRVR:DB8PR03MB5548;H:eu22-emailsignatures-cloud.codetwo.com;FPR:;SPF:Pass;LANG:en;PTR:eu22-emailsignatures-cloud.codetwo.com;A:1;MX:1;
```

This caused the following parsing error from Mime4j:

```
org.apache.james.mime4j.MimeIOException: org.apache.james.mime4j.io.MaxLineLimitException: Maximum line length limit (1000) exceeded
```

I was able to workaround this problem by configuring Mime4J to accept longer lines:

```
    msgFactory.setAttribute(
      "MimeEntityConfig",
      new MimeConfig.Builder().setMaxLineLen(2000).build() );
```

I doubled it to 2000 as I have plenty of head-room in terms of heap space, so that's not a problem.

But I could've actually fixed this by just bumping the max line length to 1001.
It seems more than coincidental that this header line is exactly 999 characters long and the default `Mime4J` value is 1000.

This whole issue is probably an off-by-one error caused by the fact that the mail that was received was terminated with windows line-endings (i.e. two bytes instead of one).

It seems like `MS Forefront` and `Mime4j` agree with each other in that the max length is 1000, just someone got their wires crossed about line-endings.

Googling gave me this SO answer which implies there is no standard max length:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2721849/924597

Is there a "correct" value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTP defines a [maximum line length of 1000](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.1.6) octets including the  new line sequence.

Seems like the forefront software is the one with a bug.

That said, it’s silly for software to not properly deal with arbitrarily long lines. You shouldn’t need to define a max length at all.

In the .NET space, my MIME parser library has no defined max line length for the parser, it only has max line lengths defined for formatting output in order to comply with the specs.

Comment: I've always assumed the various limits in the Mime4J and other mail handling libraries are about handling malicious/accidental edge cases (i.e. mail-bombs that can crash/DoS a service).

Answer (score 0):

The standard as indicated by `jstedfast` is the real answer.
But be aware that Microsoft (who else) Outlook may generate lines in the `References` header a bit longer than that (up to 1012 ish).

See https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/9bmjbv/email_rejected_due_to_lengthy_references_in_email/e547vaf/