# Line length limit in SMTP emails [Was: Message length limit sending HTML email with smtplib]

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

Here's a simple test that demonstrates the problem I'm seeing:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

my_addr = 'my_email@my_domain.com'

str = ''
for i in range(500):
    str += f'{i}: <a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a><br>'

msg = EmailMessage()
msg.set_content('')
msg.add_alternative(str, subtype='html')
msg['Subject'] = 'html test'
msg['From'] = my_addr
msg.add_header('reply-to', my_addr)
msg['To'] = my_addr

with smtplib.SMTP('localhost', timeout=30) as smtp_server:
    smtp_server.send_message(msg)
```

The resulting email seems to "break" about every 1000 bytes in the input html.  This length includes any tags in the HTML string.  The received email looks something like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've tried different SMTP servers with different message length limits, but all were set to 10M or higher, so I doubt this had any effect.  Also, I receive no error codes or exceptions.  Everything sends cleanly.  smtplib just seems to break up the message somehow.

Any idea what the problem is or how to correct this?

Comment: Python should take care of this for you (it does this automatically behind the scenes for a number of other scenarios where this is necessary), and I can't repro; `print(message.as_string())` on my computer shows the message is neatly wrapped in quoted-printable encoding with line wraps every 78 characters https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfPjz.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**
It is a result of line line length limit imposed by SMTP servers.
It causes breaking too long lines.

**Solution:**
Insert line break characters into your html string.

```
for i in range(500):
  str += f'{i}: <a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a><br>\n'
```

`tidy` program may be used to break long HTML lines (among other things).

**Links:**
[Is there an accepted maximum line length for SMTP header fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57174013/is-there-an-accepted-maximum-line-length-for-smtp-header-fields)

Comment: That was exactly it.  I'm not sure whether the problem was with the SMTP server or with the Outlook client rendering it, but breaking the lines op solves the problem.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: On further review, it's definitely happening at the SMTP server.  The source email is broken into ~1000 byte chunks, making a mess of the HTML.